# Alternatives to avoid domain from being blacklisted

Tags: email, shared-hosting, blacklist-prevention

We outsource our web and email hosting to a web hosting company and occasionally I get complaints from our clients or internal staff that mail from our domain does not reach the intended recipient or they end up in the intended recipient's junk mail.

I've contacted our hosting provider on this and they did help us with a few unblock requests but it will certainly end up being in the blacklist again after a few days.

We're on shared hosting and I'm wondering if there is an alternative to prevent our domain from being blacklisted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can raise your credibility towards other servers by

- using [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) to sign your mails
- setting a proper [SPF-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)
- doing virus scans on outgoing mails
- try to get far far far away from a shared mailserver because they can ruin all your efforts
- use a third-party service that maintains a better reputation by being proactive against spam, like Mandrill, SendGrid, Postmark, Amazon SES, etc

P.S. This list is open for additions

Comment: You can also use a third-party service that maintains a better reputation by being proactive against spam, like Mandrill, SendGrid, Postmark, Amazon SES, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I added yours to the list

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Point 5 do look interesting. Can it be integrated to my existing shared hosting?

Answer (score 3):

Additions to the list @ChristopherPerrin provided:

- You must have correct DNS records
- MX record(s) should points to the A record, not CNAME.
- You should avoid of using ip address in MX records
- A record should preferred point to the MX records and vice versa
- For relay mails you should use smtp authentication
- You should periodically analyze mail log to examine any abnormal activity to avoid falling into black lists